# How do I create multiple arrays with one csv in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with a table with three columns. Essentially what I am doing is trying to generate html fragments with a nesting structure. I believe I can do this using arrays. My question is how do I go about creating multiple arrays (1 per column) and make it go through continuous loops to create a nesting structure for the output.

Example table that will be a csv file.

```
Parent ID      Element     
A              1
B              2
C              3
D              4
E              5
E              6
A              7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, something like this should do what you want:

```
$parentID = @()
$element  = @()

Import-Csv "C:\path\to\your.csv" | % {
  $parentID += $_."Parent ID"
  $element  += $_.Element
}
```

Another (less performance-hungry) approach would be this:

```
$data = Import-Csv "C:\path\to\your.csv"
$parentID = $data | % { $_."ParentID" }
$element  = $data | % { $_.Element }
```

The array `$parentID` will contain all values from the `Parent ID` column, the array `$element` all values from the `Element` column:

```
PS C:\> $parentID
A
B
C
D
E
E
A
PS C:\> $element
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: `$parentID += $_."Parent ID"` will recreate the array every time. For many elements performance will be an issue.

Comment: @Neolisk Thanks for pointing that out. I added an alternative method that should show better performance.

Comment: Just curious how does it work under the hood? `$data | % { $_."ParentID" }` Does it maintain a list and then casts to array?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PowerShell's inner workings, but it might well be something like that. I just conducted a test with an input array of 100000 values and the difference in performance is several orders of magnitude (0'06" vs. 33'15").

Comment: My next question is how do i loop through to create a nesting structure so if I have A,B,C,3 in the first column and then 1,2,3,4 in the second how do i make sure that the 4th pair gets put under or with last pair @Neolisk

Comment: Your next question should be, well, your next *question*.